# Is there a downvote cap?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

It's clearly stated that there is a 200 reputation points/day maximum for users, but what about downvotes?

Is there a daily cap on how negative your reputation points can go?

Comment: There are also bounties where you can loose rep quickly. But maybe they wouldn't count towards a possible negative cap anyway.

Comment: @Trilarion: Excellent point.

Comment: Would you like us to all down-vote this question so you can find out? ;)

Comment: @Necreaux But meta down votes don't affect your reputation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is there a daily cap on how negative your rep can go?

Other than the hard minimum reputation of 1, I'm not aware of any *daily* limits for rep loss. If there is one, then us deleting sock puppets gladly ignores this limit.

> Is there a badge for this?

Badges are there to reward good behavior (or as a consolation prize for something that is out of your control, e.g. Tumbleweed). Reputation is a measure of how much the community trusts you. Losing this reputation, especially in large amounts, is almost certainly neither good nor worth pitying — if anything, it just means that you've lost a good amount of that trust, or worse, that you've never really earned it in the first place (see above).

Comment: The "is there a badge" bit was meant to be a lighthearted joke, but I've removed it.

Comment: Although it is quite odd that a user can have their rep wiped out exponentially faster than they can accrue it.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr: Realistically, though, it can only happen when a popular answer is deleted or an account with lots of votes for the user is deleted. It takes 5 downvotes to cancel out a single upvote, so it's going to take a lot of downvotes to really hurt someone. There's also the daily voting limit, which means a single downvoter can only do so much damage - and even that is going to get reversed the next day anyway.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr: keep in mind that you can stop and even revert an ordinary downvote flood by removing the offending posting. For users who participate seriously, it is rather hard to get their rep “wiped out … faster than they can accrue it” (not to speak of “exponentially”).

Comment: Very true. Deleting would negate it.

Comment: You lose rep for deleting sockpuppets? That doesn't seem fair.

Comment: @acbabis: Just your everyday occupational hazard ;)

Comment: I though diamonds get bigger with each sockpuppet destroyed - so BlotClocks' one is twice as big as the rest :)

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: I'm pretty sure it's the other way around!

Comment: Don't forget bounties! Some users have offered tens of thousands of reputation in the form of bounties.